# Monogame "lighting" specific objects

Tags: c#, monogame, lighting

I have done something similar to this in Monogame:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

My question is, what would I have to do to draw that lighting effect **only on the pillar** and not the background ? Is there something like ignoring certain sprites when using `BlendState.Additive` ? How would that work ? Here is how i'm drawing it now.

```
//draw background
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Opaque);
spriteBatch.Draw(Background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

//draw pillar
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred);
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(PillarX, PillarY, Width, Height), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

//draw lighting sprite in additive mode
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Additive);
spriteBatch.Draw(LightTexture, pos, null, Color.OrangeRed, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 
    scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: XNA or Monogame? They are not 100% the same

Comment: @MickyDuncan monogame, well yea they are 95% same, the other 5% is mostly not implemented stuff

Comment: Thank-you. I have removed the `xna` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have 2 options:

- Use a pixel shader to render the lighting sprite only on the desired area or
- Use the stencil buffer and render the pillar into it before you aplly the lighting sprite.

I won't explain this in detail because both ways are explained extensively at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/best-way-to-mask-2d-sprites-in-xna) of the gamedev stackexchange.

Comment: which one would you recommend ?

Comment: I personally would go with the stencil buffer because its exactly the purpose of it to make "stencils" for such situations, esp. in 3D applications.

Comment: how can i mask a 3D model ? i dont think thats possible ? I need to know how to do this also, because i need to "light" up not only the pillar but 3D models as well with that method, do you know if this is possible ?

Comment: You do not really mask the 3D model but the rendered silhouette of it. Its the same procedure as with the Sprite: You first render the model into your scene, then into the stencil buffer and after that you render the lighting sprite with the active stencil buffer.